# Unusual symbols highlighting after calling colorscheme command

Tags: vim, haskell, color-scheme

I've encountered the strange `:colorscheme` command behavior.

I have some unusual symbols generated by [haskell-conceal script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3200) like `∷` and `→`. I have no `colorscheme` option in my `.vimrc`, so these symbols are displayed in normal way:

[image]

After calling `:colorscheme default` command these symbols are highlighted:

[image]

it will be great to understand what's going on after calling this command and what exactly affects this behavior.

**UPD**:

- Can you post the text here in non-image form so we can try to reproduce it?

`client ∷ Nick → Handle → IO ()`

- What is the name of the file you're editing?

`*.hs`

- ... the output of `:set filetype`

`filetype=haskell`

Comment: Can you post the text here in non-image form so we can try to reproduce it?  Also, what is the name of the file you're editing, and the output of `:set filetype?` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get the encoding right to get those symbols to display properly, but their highlighting is in the group `hsNiceOperator`.

Therefore, `hi hsNiceOperator guifg=... guibg=...` should handle it. Or the equivalent if you're not using GVim but the console one.

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ - Before or after - it shouldn't make any difference. Of course, replace the ...'s with the actual colors.

Comment: I set these options in the `haskell.vim` syntax file, but result is actually the same.

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ - Uhmm, what options? The "hi hsNic..." or ? In general it is a good practice to set everything in your vimrc, not in the plugin files. Saves you the trouble when you're updating your plugins (and some plugin managers do that semi-automatically, therefore overwriting your customizations).

Comment: Looks like that order of these commands is important. If I load conceal config _before_ the `colorscheme` command - corrupted highlight appears. If I load conceal config _after_ colorscheme command - it's all ok.

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ - On second thought, that's right. That's how it's supposed to work. If your plugin is somewhere linking hsNic... to let's say SpecialKey or something, it will overwrite this custom hi. Never mind now; does that solve your problem?